# How get new data from database after change java ee

Tags: java, postgresql, ejb, entitymanager

In my method  I  modified a data in the database and I want in the same method  to retrieve my new data java ee  application

NB: I am using the entitymanager in my accountRepository 
Example

```
 @Transactional(value = Transactional.TxType.SUPPORTS)
    public Account getAccount(Account account) {
    
        accountRepository.create(new Account("test");
    
        return accountRepository.getAllAccount();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flush and refresh methods : entity manager.refresh(entity);